# How can an apps application class run at once the device starts?

Tags: android

How can an apps application class run at once the device starts?

Hello,

I have an application where the application class is running it's onCreate, but no activites on device startup. And i don't mean when the BOOT broadcast is sent, i mean at once the device is started.

I can see this since i've added file logging to the appliation class, but i cannot see that it comes any further (into any activities).

My manifest has

- No receivers
- No services with their own process id

Is there anything else that could start my application class on device start?

When i click and start the application on my device, i see logs in the application class again, but this time it has another process id than it had.

Thanks in advance!

===================

ok, so after commenting out all obvious code and manifest entries, i finally set my Sync Adapter Service to enabled=false, and then the problem did not occur. Is this normal behaviour of a sync adapter service?

Comment: isn't the `BOOT broadcast` sent when the device is STARTED ???

Comment: I think this is feature in android that starts the processes/apps on startup that were running while shutting down.

Comment: you can create a service and call it on `BOOT_COMPLETED` event

Comment: BOOT_COMPLETED isn't sent before approximately 30 seconds, this happens at once.......

@SRBbans, that might be right. I'm in my app, reboot the device, and then i see that this happens

Comment: there is no way to run apps on boot except using `BOOT_COMPLETE`. At least without root.

Comment: @VladMatvienko: That was my thoughts as well... it's just weird that the Application class is called at once the device has started. I think SRBbans might be onto something

Comment: @Ikky try one more thing.. close your app completely, i mean even remove from recent menu and then try to restart it.

Comment: @SRBbans - Opened the app like usual, clicked recent apps, closed all. Rebooted... Application class still run after reboot.

Comment: ok, so after commenting out all obvious, i finally set my Sync Service to enabled=false, and then the problem did not occur. Is this normal behaviour of a sync adapter service?